# Mongodb addFields from an async/await function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

I am trying to aggregate rooms data then add new fields into it. However, since the rooms itself is an await function, it will return the value of rooms before the forEach function takes place. How should I address such issue? console.log will return:

```
a, rooms
b, rooms
(notification_count value)
```

Below is the code that I am trying to use:

```
let rooms = await this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        userIds: { $all: [userId] },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "userIds",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "userProfiles",
      },
    },
  ]).sort({ updatedAt: -1 });

  console.log("a", rooms);

  rooms.forEach(async (room) => {
    const notification_count =
      await ChatMessageModel.getUnreadMessagesCountByRoomId(
        room._id,
        userId,
        "is_read"
      );
    room["notification_count"] = notification_count;
    console.log(notification_count);
  });

  console.log("b", rooms);
```

**UPDATE**
Using for loop instead of forEach worked based on my code workflow. I can use the code as of now. However if there is a way where I can insert the code directly in aggregate/addFields, that would be great. `getUnreadMessagesCountByRoomId()` only returns int.

Comment: async/await with `.forEach` never works as you think ... use a `for` loop with async/await instead,

Comment: Thank you.. using for loop instead worked.

Comment: "_if there is a way where I can insert the code directly in aggregate/addFields, that would be greate_" - which code? I think you're referring to the `room["notification_count"]` part - but you haven't actually shaerd with us what the `getUnreadMessagesCountByRoomId()` function is, so we don't know what logic/code you want to add in here.

Comment: The `getUnreadMessagesCountByRoomId()` only returns an int.